# how to control browser resize

Tags: html, resize, effect

How to avoid the **resizing of html elements** while browser tries *zoom* it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's no method to do this, because that's the whole point of zoom.

eg. A user who has poor eyesight might wish to zoom in. The scaling is done by the browser during render time and doesn't interact with your page at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent resizing when zooming, you might need to rethink your layoutdesign, 'cause it's not zoom-proof